# Struts2 map with dynamic key

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

**jsp**

```jsp
<s:set var="cnt" value="1" />
<s:iterator value="assemblydebates">
<s:if test='%{(#cnt%4)==1}'>
<h4 style="color: #FACC2E;" class="text-left"><s:property value="archives1[#cnt]"/></h4>
</s:if>
..................
<s:set var="cnt" value="%{#cnt + 1}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Where `archives1` is a map `(LinkedHashMap<String,String>)` of values `{4=Assembly Debates, 8=Party Press Meets, 12=Promos, 16=Archives}`.

**Problem** with above code. Here `archives1[#cnt]` is not printed. If I use like `archives1['4']` then its printing.

And I also checked through iterator

```jsp
<s:iterator value="archives1">  
<span id="pid" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="getvideos('<s:property value='value'/>');"><s:property value='value'/></span> 
</s:iterator>
```

This piece of code is working.

Can any one tell me that whats the problem here.

**Edit:**

```jsp
  <s:set var="cnt" value="%{1}" />
  <s:iterator value="assemblydebates">
  <s:if test='%{(#cnt%4)==1}'>
  <h4 style="color: #FACC2E;" class="text-left"><s:property value="archives1[#cnt]"/></h4>
  </s:if>
  <s:if test='%{(#cnt%4)==0}'>
  <div style="display:inline-block;background-color: #ffffff;"><img src="images/more1.png" title="Read more.." style="width:30px;height:30px;cursor:pointer;" onClick="getvideos('<s:property value="%{archives1[#cnt]}"/>');"/></div>
  </s:if>
  <s:set var="cnt" value="%{#cnt+1}"/>
  </s:iterator>
```

**Problem:**  `<h4 style="color: #FACC2E;" class="text-left"><s:property value="archives1[#cnt]"/></h4>` not prints a value

If I try `<h4 style="color: #FACC2E;" class="text-left"><s:property value="archives1['4']"/></h4>` it prints a value. So `if` condition evaluated.

The remaining code works well.

Comment: Is archives1[4] (without the quotes) printing?

Comment: `archives1[4]` is printing

Comment: `<s:set var="cnt" value="1" />` is number. Use `<s:set var="cnt" value="'1'" />`.